# how to initialize PCB in an operating system like Linux？

Tags: operating-system

```
typedef struct PCB
{
    void *tf;
    uint8_t kstack[KSTACK_SIZE];
} PCB

//this is the structure
```

Comment: `PCB newPCB = calloc(1,sizeof(PCB));`. If this is not what you want then consider adding some more explanation.

Answer (score 0):

In this question "PCB" likely means "Process Control Block". In Linux terms I think this would be [`task_struct`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/ident?i=task_struct).

The first `task_struct` is initialized by [`INIT_TASK`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/ident?i=INIT_TASK).

Other processes are created with `fork(2)`, `clone(2)` etc. All of these end up calling [`do_fork`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/ident?i=do_fork). The heavy lifting of actually creating a new `task_struct` is done by copying the old one in [`copy_process`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/ident?i=copy_process) which in turn calls [`dup_task_struct`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/ident?i=dup_task_struct)